# How can I concatenate the last name and remove the middle name?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate the last name and remove the middle name

```
fullName = "De Risio, Paul William";

fullName.split(','); // complete last name to array

lastName = fullName[0]; // get complete last name

tmp = lastName.split(" ").join(""); // remove space in lastName

firstAndMid = fullName[1]; // get string after "," delimiter

firstAndMid.split(" "); // first and middle name delimited with " " to array

firstName = firstAndMid[0]; // get only first name

alert(tmp + ", " +firstName);   // ==> D, e
```

The problem is I want "DeRisio, Paul" and instead I am getting "D, e". I am pretty far off the mark. **What gives?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning the result of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to anything, so you are still working on the strings instead of an array when you do e.g. `lastName = fullName[0];`.

```js
fullName = "De Risio, Paul William";

names = fullName.split(/,\s*/); // complete last name to array

lastName = names[0]; // get complete last name

tmp = lastName.split(" ").join(""); // remove space in lastName

firstAndMid = names[1]; // get string after "," delimiter

first = firstAndMid.split(" "); // first and middle name delimited with " " to array

firstName = first[0]; // get only first name

console.log(tmp + ", " +firstName);   // ==> D, e
```

Note you need to split on `,` followed by spaces (`/,\s*/`), otherwise `first[0]` will be an empty string due to the space at the start of `firstAndMid`.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Split doesn't work in place, it creates a new array.

### Solution

```js
let fullName = "De Risio, Paul William";

fullName = fullName.split(', '); // complete last name to array

lastName = fullName[0]; // get complete last name

let tmp = lastName.split(" ").join(""); // remove space in lastName

let firstAndMid = fullName[1]; // get string after "," delimiter

firstAndMid = firstAndMid.split(" "); // first and middle name delimited with " " to array

let firstName = firstAndMid[0]; // get only first name

console.log(tmp + ", " +firstName);   // ==> D, e
```

I would do this like this:

```js
const fullName = "De Risio, Paul William";
const [lastName, names] = fullName.split(', ')
const [firstName] = names.split(' ')
const result = [lastName.replace(' ', ''), firstName].join(', ')
console.log(result)
```